# Best way to write equation with conditions

Tags: equations

I have an equation

```
\[
    f\left(x,y,z\right)= 
\begin{cases}
    q,& \text{if } \left(x,y,z\right)=\left(x_0,y_0,z_0\right)\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
```

But I think this is wired, what is the best way to describe the x, y, z

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 3):

What is "best" is certainly a matter of opinion. I would like to recommend, though, that you write out three separate conditions instead of making people's eyes flicker back and forth between two row vectors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{\large before}
\[
    f\left(x,y,z\right)= 
\begin{cases}
    q,& \text{if } \left(x,y,z\right)=\left(x_0,y_0,z_0\right)\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]

\medskip
\textcolor{red}{\large after}
\[
f(x,y,z)= 
\begin{cases}
    q& \text{if $x=x_0$, $y=y_0$, and $z=z_0$;}\\
    0& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```